# How do I attach geth to this node?

Tags: go-ethereum, networkid

Apparently they are running a full node which we can attach our geth.

> We are running 4 public Geth nodes in AWS EC2 and you can attach or
>   RPC to them.
>
> IP address: 52.208.46.161
>
> Main net, it is a full node and started with:

```
geth --port 30302 --rpc --rpcport 8546 --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,web3,net" --lightserv 25 --lightpeers 50 RPC port: 8546
```

but when I do

```
geth attach http://52.208.46.161:8546
```

I get

```
Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: api modules: Post http://52.208.46.161:8546: dial tcp 52.208.46.161:8546: getsockopt: connection refused
```

I hardly think that post is out of date as it's only a week old. How can I check the status of such a node?

http://help.b9lab.com/eth-developer-course-technical-help/our-public-geth-nodes

Comment: it is not possible to attach via HTTP, only via IPC, but IPC works only locally, it is not something to use remotely by design. Just send HTTP requests to their node. You may download MyEtherWallet and specify this node as a Custon Node and use it for your needs

Answer (score 1):

maybe u can try

> geth --rpc --rpcaddr 52.208.46.161 --rpcport 8546 attach http://0.0.0.0:8546

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach to the IPC file.

e.g. `geth attach ~/.ethereum/geth.ipc`.